# How to validate required items of JSON SCHEMA array

Tags: php, json, laravel, jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema for new orders, that consists of order list and address.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "properties": {
    "order": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "properties": {
          "product_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "product_id",
          "quantity"
        ]
      }
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "array",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "address1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state_or_region": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "phone",
        "address1",
        "city",
        "state_or_region",
        "country"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "order",
    "address"
  ]
}
```

But it doesn't seem to actually validate the items at all (I'm using `Laravel 5.2` with `"justinrainbow/json-schema": "~2.0"` ):

```
$refResolver = new \JsonSchema\RefResolver(new \JsonSchema\Uri\UriRetriever(), new \JsonSchema\Uri\UriResolver());
$schema = $refResolver->resolve(storage_path('schemas\orders.post.json'));

$errors = [];
$input = Request::input();

// Validate
$validator = new \JsonSchema\Validator();
$validator->check($input, $schema);

$msg = [];
if ($validator->isValid()) {
    return Response::json(['valid'], 200, [], $this->pritify);
} else {
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['message'] = "JSON does not validate";
    foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error) {
        $msg['errors'][] = [
            'error' => ($error['property'] = ' ') ? 'wrong_data' : $error['property'],
            'message' => $error['message']
        ];
    }
    return Response::json($msg, 422, [], $this->pritify);
}
```

A request like this always comes valid:

```
{
    "order": [
        {
            "product_id": 100,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "product_id": 0,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    "address": []
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com . My IDE threw errors about the trailing commas after the brackets after `"country"`

Comment: Sorry, removed it. There is more to validate, this is a shortened example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed array and object types. The only array value in your scheme must be order. Fixed scheme:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "order": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "product_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "product_id",
          "quantity"
        ]
      }
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "address1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state_or_region": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "phone",
        "address1",
        "city",
        "state_or_region",
        "country"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "order",
    "address"
  ]
}
```

And validation errors I got with you test data:

```
JSON does not validate. Violations:
[address.name] The property name is required
[address.phone] The property phone is required
[address.address1] The property address1 is required
[address.city] The property city is required
[address.state_or_region] The property state_or_region is required
[address.country] The property country is required
```

Comment: hmm, but in this case I get `"Array value found, but an object is required"`, since `$input = Request::input();` creates an array like structure

Comment: In your data example "address": [] but it will be object like "address": {"name": "Kostya"} so your validation error is correct too. I believe all confusion is because PHP empty array can be represented as JSON empty array or JSON empty object, but PHP associative array can be represented as JSON object only.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is just how Laravel handles requests. I solved the problem by adding `$input = json_decode(json_encode($input));` after request.